# Functions that are integrable with respect to counting measure

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\eta$ be the counting measure on the natural numbers, $N$. Characterize the nonnegative real-valued functions (that is, sequences) that are integrable over $N$ with respect to $\eta$ and the value of $\int_N f d\eta$.

Answer (score 5):

Your functions are sequences, so think about the corresponding series, and note that functions $f$ can be written
$$
f=\sum_{n\geq 0}f(n)\;1_{\{n\}}.
$$
By the way, this proves that every function is measurable here. Which ones are integrable now?

Comment: Well the characteristic function produces values of 1 or 0 depending on whether we have an element in N or not. So, would the ones that are integrable be when we are in N?

Comment: No. For a nondecreasing sequence of nonnegative measurable functions $f_k$, we always have $\int \lim_k f_k=\lim_k \int f_k$. That's the monotone convergence theorem. So take $f$ and consider the sequence of partial sums $f_k=\sum_{n=0}^kf(n)1_{\{n\}}$. Since this is a finite sum, we can compute $\int f_k=\sum_{n=0}^kf(n)\int 1_{\{n\}}$.

Comment: Now by definition, $\int 1_{\{n\}}=\eta (\{n\})=1$. So $\int f_k=\sum_{k=1}^nf(n)$, the partial sum of the series. Note that $f$ is the pontwise limit if the $f_k$. Hence $\int f=\int \lim_k f_k=\lim_{k\rightarrow+\infty}\int f_k=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} f(n)$. Your function is integrable if and only if the series $\sum_{n\geq0} f(n)$ converges.